# WPF firebird primary key violation

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, firebird

In a WPF project, I connect to a Firebird database for Model, and then I try to insert an item into one of the tables that has a Primary key declared.

I get this error:

> Violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint \"PK_ARTI_1\" on table
>   \"ARTI\"
>
> Problematic key value is (\"ID\" = 0)

My Firebird table has this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTI
(
  ID Integer NOT NULL,
  NAME Varchar(100),
  DESCRIPTION Varchar(200),
  TAX Decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_ARTI_1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
ALTER TABLE ARTI ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ARTI_1
  FOREIGN KEY (IDTAX) REFERENCES TAX (ID) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE
 ON ARTI TO  SYSDBA WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Also I have a trigger (generator) for the autoincrement ID as follows:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER TRIGGER ARTI_BI ACTIVE
BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN

IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_ARTI_ID, 1);

END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

(this was automatically generated in a different way but I stripped some code according to some other SO question/answer)

If I try to save an item through Entity Framework, I get the above error. I do not actually know how to access/see the actual insert table, because it is done behind the scenes with the Entity Framework, but I definitely don't assign any value to the ID field.

My item adding code is this:

```
using (ArtEntities context = new ArtEntities())
{
            ARTI art = new ARTI();
            art.NAME = tbname.Text;
            art.DESCRIPTION = tbdesc.Text;
            art.TAX = decimal.Parse(cbTAX.Text);

            context.ARTIs.Add(art);
            context.SaveChanges();

            int idu = art.ID;
}
```

In the last line I try to GET the value of the ID of the inserted row, but it does not get there. It stops at `SaveChanges()` where probably the DB operations are being done by the Entity Framework.

the Model cs file for the table looks like this:

--- ARTI.cs ---

```
namespace TestXXX
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ARTI
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public decimal TAX { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also must mention that the table is empty when I try to add the new item to it. So there is no other value with an ID of 0 in the table..

What can I do to avoid this error?

This seems to me like some kind of bug maybe?

**NEW EDIT**
I've made changes to the TRIGGER so it would expect ID value of 0, like this:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER TRIGGER ARTI_BI ACTIVE
BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE tmp DECIMAL(18,0);
BEGIN
  IF ((NEW.ID IS NULL)OR(NEW.ID = 0)) THEN
    NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_ARTI_ID, 1);
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    tmp = GEN_ID(GEN_ARTI_ID, 1);
    if (tmp < new.ID) then
      tmp = GEN_ID(GEN_ARTI_ID, new.ID-tmp);
  END
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

but now, When I do the insert (EF), after

```
        context.ARTIs.Add(art);
        context.SaveChanges();
        int idu = art.ID;
```

I display my ID using a MessageBox and the value is always ZERO (0). And when I check the table using FlameRobin, I can see a different number in the ID field for my new row. So it seems that EF does execute the insert, but it does not return the actual inserted ID, but the one that he sent to the server... or so it seems from where I sit.

How can I get the REAL inserted ID after SaveChanges()?

Comment: I tried to insert manually (FireRobin) a record  into the table (without specifying the ID) and it works. Why doesn't it work from WPF

Comment: The default value of `int` is `0`, so it doesn't enter the trigger as `null`.

Comment: Nice catch @Gert Arnold. However, I changed my trigger to expect 0 for ID as well as NULL, still, when I insert a new record and request it back after SaveChanges() I still got 0 even if looking directly in the Table I see that the inserted ID is something different. So basically, I insert a new row in the table using EF, I do not assign a value for ID, the insert goes ok, but the EF tells me that the ID of the inserted value is 0 (and it is not). How can I get the actual ID inserted?

Comment: With SQL Server, EF queries SCOPE_IDENTITY right after the insert. I assume that the Firebird data provider does something similar, but it probably doesn't pick up the modified value. You should check the executed SQL statements to find out and maybe get a hint how to solve it.

Comment: How do I check the executed SQL Stetements? I am new at this WPF Entity Framework stuff, and WPF in general. Please elaborate

Comment: set `contex.Database.Log`

Comment: `Database does not contain a definition for Log and no extension method Log...`

Comment: I downloaded FB Trace Manager for Firebird (trial) and I can see there all kinds of actions, but I do not see anything about selecting an ID value after the insert. I can see the statement, and the parameters, but it's only the insert statement (and yes the param received by FB is 0 for ID, you were clearly right). So it seems that EF does not do this for Firebird. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Hmm... that's not how a query provider should be implemented. Could be a feature request. In the mean time if you really need the new ID value (which is pretty rare in my experience) you'd have to find it yourself by querying the last ID where ... (and "where" is something like comparing some natural key of the inserted object). Not entirely concurrency safe, so you have to hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a possible solution for this issue would be for me to use UUIDs instead of IDs. This way I can generate them before inserting and that way I can know the UUID without having to query the table after insert - avoiding the concurrency problem.